# Possible to auto fill code statements in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, audio, numbers, auto

I'm currently creating a soundboard app. I have about 100+ sound files to import.

I have code lines (android:onClick="song1") and (MediaPlayer mysound1).

Just wondering if there is a way to copy+paste these lines and have android studio auto change the line to "song2" and "song3" all the way to "song100"? Same goes for the "mysound1" all the way to "mysound100". I hope I do not have to do it manually :(

Thank you!

Comment: You could create them dynamically in a loop in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you're using seems like a brute force method. There are much more elegant ways to approach this. For one, I would recommend creating dynamic Android components programmatically instead of in XML. Then you could hold all of your elements in a List or a Map, and you could tie them to a generic onClick listener. I'd recommend taking a look around online to figure out how to do some of these things.

But, if you would like to stick with you original method, I don't believe that Android has a way to auto number your click events. You could, however, write code to write your code. Here's a simple example using Java - since you're writing an Android app (utilizing the Eclipse console to print out to):

```
public class WriteMyCode {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        sb.append("<Button android:id=\"@+id/mybutton\"\n");
        sb.append("  android:layout_width=\"wrap_content\"\n");
        sb.append("  android:layout_height=\"wrap_content\"\n");
        sb.append("  android:text=\"Click me!\"\n");
        sb.append("  android:onClick=\"" + "song" +  i + "\" />\n\n");
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
  }
}
```

You can then copy the output from the Eclipse console and paste it into your Android XML resource file.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I just started android studio =P so i guess i'll check up on this eclipse console and StringBuffer function.

Answer (score 0):

I went to use Microsoft Excel to auto fill the numbers all the way to 100. Then CONCATENATE the ; to the end of "Mediaplayer mysound1".